# Bigquery Grouping wildcard tables date time in the UI / Sharded tables

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I get the Bigquery UI to cluster tables together, but also have time format (Sharded tables).

For example, tables that end with `YYYYmmdd` get clustered get grouped correctly (as seen in the pic below).

```
a_table_20220101
a_table_20220102 

my_table_20220101 
my_table_20220102
```

**What format do I need to get the time to also group together, e.g. `my_other_table_20220101_0500`**

[image]